# Windows Batch - Protect special characters in a variable

Tags: batch-file, escaping, special-characters

A command needs to use a sequence looking like this one: `Z;[%&.:mn=WO`. **The following call works**:

```
D:\Some_folder> some_command -s "Z;[%&.:mn=WO"
```

The aim is to embed this call in a batch file, whose behavior isn't than the interactive mode one.

As you can see, there are several special characters, so it has to be protected before use. The batch file looks like the sample below:

```
set SEQUENCE=<sequence>
call %SOMEREP%\command -s %SEQUENCE% REM blah blah blah
```

Using **`set SEQUENCE="Z;[%&.:mn=WO"`** will fail, and surprisingly, with `echo on`, the displayed **line** before execution is **exactly the same** as the one in **interactive mode**, which works. Actually,  the command line complains that the sequence should only contains ASCII characters in a range of 33-256, and be exactly 12 characters length. As is the quotes became a part of the value.

The attempt to protect each characters fails, with or without quotes:

- With `set SEQUENCE=Z^;[^^%%^&.:mn^=WO`, the line will be:

  ```
  D:\Some_folder> some_command -s Z;[%  & .:mn=WO
  ```

  It produces the error "The system cannot find the drive" (sounds like `.:` is interpreted as a drive switching)
- With `set SEQUENCE="Z^;[^^%%^&.:mn^=WO"`, the line will be:

  ```
  D:\Some_folder> some_command -s "Z^;[^^%^&.:mn^=WO"
  ```

  It complains about the sequence size, as well as the first attempt

Other character escaping attempt were tried without success, like quote escaping inside quoted string (`""`). What point is missed here? Asking before rewriting it in Bash.

---

Update: I noticed this morning that the reproduced attempts show a double caret (`^^`). I don't recall why it was done. I let it in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a `batch-file`, `cmd` will consume the first `%` so just double up on it:

```
set "SEQUENCE=Z;[%%&.:mn=WO"
some_command -s "%SEQUENCE%"
```

or if you want to retain the double quotes as part of the value, which is not preferred though:

```
set SEQUENCE="Z;[%%&.:mn=WO"
some_command -s %SEQUENCE%
```

If needed to use it without the surrounding double quotes, directly from the command, you need to double up on `%` and escape the `&` else the ampersand will be seen as a chaining operator:

```
some_command -s Z;[%%^&.:mn=WO
```

a Good source, in table form, for all of the escape sequences can be found on [Robvanderwoude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

**EDIT**

To explicitly `call` it, simply double on the variable `%` again:

```
set SEQUENCE="Z;[%%&.:mn=WO"
call some_command -s "%%SEQUENCE%%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling the command is generally unnecessary unless you have variables set in a loop and delayed expansion isn't enabled (I used to explicitly avoid delayed expansion and use calls then I needed it instead.)

Assuming that `%SOMEREP%` was not set in a code block (and therefore no need to `Call` it) then the following should do.

Essentially just double the % once on the Variable, unless you really do need to call, in which case you quadruple it.

No Call:

```
Set "_CMD=%SOMEREP%\command"
Set "_SEQUENCE=Z;[%%&.:mn=WO"
"%_CMD%" -s "%_SEQUENCE%"
REM blah blah
```

Assuming you have actual need to `call` the command, the following escapes the `%` twice by using the `%%%%`

```
Set "_CMD=%SOMEREP%\command"
Set "_SEQUENCE=Z;[%%%%&.:mn=WO"
call "%_CMD%" -s "%_SEQUENCE%"
REM blah blah
```

Ignore the original bit about the carrots, I wrote this as I was waking this AM and apparently my brain was still thinking about some commands I was runnign the day prior and got confused, as at the CMD CLI you need to use `^` to escape `%` to force the delayed expansion of some variables.

Comment: You cannot escape `%` with caret. batch always consumes the first `%`. You escape `%` by doubling up `%%` Go ahead and test it from a batch file (not cmd). `echo "%i"` vs `echo "%%i"` vs `echo "^%i"` if you don't feel like testing, read the first column [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Yup, you're rightn no need to test, thanks for catching that. 
 I write most of these while getting ready in the morning, and that was a complete brain slip-up on my part.  I know where the issue lies now that my head is clear and I think about it, I was working on the CMD CLI Yesterday and using the carrots to force delayed expansion of a called echo to update the value of the data and it just sort of got stuck.  In any case thanks for that :)

Comment: That is why it is always best to have coffee first thing in the morning.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard  Haha, I hear you, but I can;t do that so well anymore, I usually try to wait into the afternoon, coffee makes me crash after an hour or two and each cup gives diminishing returns, I have started drinking in the evenings ad then going to sleep an hour or two later.  I think it's something to do with how my routine has changed due to having young children to look after.

Comment: When you use `CALL` you should double the percents `CALL "%_CMD%" -s "%%_SEQUENCE%%"` else carets are doubled inside the quotes

Comment: @Jeb No carrots, just `%`s the carrots were never going to do anything of value here

Comment: @BenPersonick Sorry, I was unclear. I spoke not about carets for escaping, instead of a caret as content of the variable like `Set "SEQ=^Z%%&"`, the caret will be doubled `CALL echo "%SEQ%"`- Output `^^Z&`,but with `CALL ECHO "%%SEQ%%"` you get the correct  output `^Z%&` and it avoids the quadruple of the percent.

Comment: @Jeb  There are no carrots in the sequence `D:\Some_folder> some_command -s "Z;[%&.:mn=WO"
`